# Tensorflow ValueError Shapes are incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Whatever I do, i can't fix this ValueError from coming up: ValueError: *Shapes (35, 1) and (700, 35) are incompatible*
I'm new to tensorflow and am trying to build a "simple", maybe still somewhat big, neural network. I have tried changing the input_shape, loss function and numbers of neurons but with no success.

I've included what I think is the important portion of code, the rest is just fetching the data and formatting it.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    #tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=700,),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(800, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(700,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(35)
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arrayInput, arrayTarget))

for feat, targ in train_dataset.take(5):
  print('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(feat, targ))

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS)


model.save('savedmodel')
```

Output:

```
Features: [8.32999992e+00 8.18400002e+00 8.10999966e+00 8.05000019e+00
 ...SHORTENED BUT 700 LONG...
 1.13643000e+05 7.27480000e+04 1.00100000e+05 3.49750000e+04], Target: [8.72999954 8.75       8.64099979 8.60000038 8.64000034 8.66499996
 8.52999973 8.51000023 8.52000046 8.56000042 8.51000023 8.95499992
 8.85999966 8.75010014 8.74499989 8.75       8.76000023 8.77000046
 8.64500046 8.65200043 8.60429955 8.69999981 8.89000034 8.97999954
 8.92000008 9.21000004 9.38000011 9.47599983 9.57999992 9.46500015
 9.44999981 9.57999992 9.625      9.76000023 9.67000008]
Features: [8.18400002e+00 8.10999966e+00 8.05000019e+00 8.10999966e+00
 ...SHORTENED BUT 700 LONG...
 7.27480000e+04 1.00100000e+05 3.49750000e+04 3.91450000e+04], Target: [8.75       8.64099979 8.60000038 8.64000034 8.66499996 8.52999973
 8.51000023 8.52000046 8.56000042 8.51000023 8.95499992 8.85999966
 8.75010014 8.74499989 8.75       8.76000023 8.77000046 8.64500046
 8.65200043 8.60429955 8.69999981 8.89000034 8.97999954 8.92000008
 9.21000004 9.38000011 9.47599983 9.57999992 9.46500015 9.44999981
 9.57999992 9.625      9.76000023 9.67000008 9.64000034]
Features: [8.10999966e+00 8.05000019e+00 8.10999966e+00 8.13199997e+00
 ...SHORTENED BUT 700 LONG...
 1.00100000e+05 3.49750000e+04 3.91450000e+04 6.92160000e+04], Target: [8.64099979 8.60000038 8.64000034 8.66499996 8.52999973 8.51000023
 8.52000046 8.56000042 8.51000023 8.95499992 8.85999966 8.75010014
 8.74499989 8.75       8.76000023 8.77000046 8.64500046 8.65200043
 8.60429955 8.69999981 8.89000034 8.97999954 8.92000008 9.21000004
 9.38000011 9.47599983 9.57999992 9.46500015 9.44999981 9.57999992
 9.625      9.76000023 9.67000008 9.64000034 9.56499958]
Features: [8.05000019e+00 8.10999966e+00 8.13199997e+00 8.11999989e+00
 ...SHORTENED BUT 700 LONG...
 9.76000023 9.67000008 9.64000034 9.56499958 9.60999966], Target: [8.60000038 8.64000034 8.66499996 
 8.52999973 8.51000023 8.52000046
 8.56000042 8.51000023 8.95499992 8.85999966 8.75010014 8.74499989
 8.75       8.76000023 8.77000046 8.64500046 8.65200043 8.60429955
 8.69999981 8.89000034 8.97999954 8.92000008 9.21000004 9.38000011
 9.47599983 9.57999992 9.46500015 9.44999981 9.57999992 9.625
 9.76000023 9.67000008 9.64000034 9.56499958 9.60999966]
Features: [8.10999966e+00 8.13199997e+00 8.11999989e+00 8.06999969e+00
 ...SHORTENED BUT 700 LONG...
 3.91450000e+04 6.92160000e+04 9.24410000e+04 1.06220000e+05], Target: [8.64000034 8.66499996 8.52999973 8.51000023 8.52000046 8.56000042
 8.51000023 8.95499992 8.85999966 8.75010014 8.74499989 8.75
 8.76000023 8.77000046 8.64500046 8.65200043 8.60429955 8.69999981
 8.89000034 8.97999954 8.92000008 9.21000004 9.38000011 9.47599983
 9.57999992 9.46500015 9.44999981 9.57999992 9.625      9.76000023
 9.67000008 9.64000034 9.56499958 9.60999966 9.63000011]
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Technik/PycharmProjects/StockNNv1/Train.py", line 88, in <module>
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:755 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:203 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:152 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:256 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1537 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4833 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\Technik\PycharmProjects\StockNNv1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (35, 1) and (700, 35) are incompatible


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Sorry for the long ouput, but as it shows, the train_dataset has 700 numbers for a feature while the target has 35, that's how I want it. **(The neural network is supposed to be able to predict the 35 vlaues from 700 given ones.)**

Comment: Could you let us know what is the shape of these two tensor's? arrayInput, arrayTarget

Comment: @PrateekBhatt sure, arrayInput: (1200, 700); arrayTarget: (1200, 35)

Comment: Is it possible to share your code over google colab so that I can debug? It can be seen clearly from the stacktrace that there is an issue with the arrayTarget.

Comment: @PrateekBhatt Ok, and now in Google Colab it's showing me another (differnet?) ValueError: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zA84bSv5XTcKY4fpvLROBIpNZDAcDuqY?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(700, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(700,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(35, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
BATCH_SIZE = 8

train_x = pd.DataFrame(data=arrayInput)
train_y = pd.DataFrame(data=arrayTarget)

model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

model.save('savedmodel')
```

I have changed the loss function from `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy` as the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` expects the targets to be of `int` but your targets are of the type `float`.

If you expect to have the `float` value as your target then it is not a classification problem but a `regression` problem and so you should use a loss function such as `MSE` or `MAE` and change the activation function of the last layer appropriately.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to fix it! It is indeed supposed to be regression, what should I use as the last activation function for that?                                                        And why is the batch size 8?

Comment: If you want your y to be between 0 and 1 then you can use sigmoid activation function.
You can also keep it blank and try to run and see the results. Also, I just choose batch_size 8, you can use whatever you want. If the example worked for you, you can accept the answer so that other could benifit from it as well.